# How to pass string from Subscriber onNext() to View?

Tags: android, rx-java, mvp, observable

Current I'm facing a problem where I wanna get a string from database and return the string to my view. Framework I using is MVP and Rxjava. Explain in details in code below:

fragment.java

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //get a string output from database by calling presenter attached with this view (fragment)
    String textFromDb = presenter.getLanguage(id);
}
```

Presenter.java

```
public String getLanguage(String id) {
    mLanguagePackDataManager.getLanguage(id)
            .subscribeOn(mDataManager.getScheduler())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String languageLabel) {
                    // >>> I need to pass this "languageLabel" to the fragment but I can't return anything from here <<<
                }
            });
}
```

So my problem here is, how do I pass the "languageLabel" to fragment so that in fragment I can use "textFromDb" to do something eg: setting this string to a textview. I know that I can create a method in View interface like `updateLabel(String text)` where the fragment will implement this method. So I call `getView().updateLabel(languageLabel)` and the fragment implementation will find the textView and set text accordingly. Is this the only method to pass something to view?

Any help will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the only way, but in my opinion is the correct one. Different layers of your app should ideally talk between themselves using `interfaces` - it gives you the most flexibility. This way it's super easy to test each layer separately, e.g. in your `presenter` layer you'd just verify you're calling the `view.updateLabel(languageLabel)` text appropriately.

Coming back to your question - there's other ways to achieve that (on top of my mind comes using some `EventBus`, but I'd just stick to plain `interfaces`

Comment: Ya, `EventBus` has come across my mind as well but the purpose is same like interfaces and ya, if compare both, i will stick with interfaces to make it standardize.

Answer (score 0):

**Presenter should have:**

```
 private viewInterface view; // reference to view

 public Presenter(viewInterface view) { //constructor for such view
        this.view = view;
    }
```

**Then in onNext you should point to view method**

```
@Override
public void onNext(String languageLabel) {
view.updateLabel(languageLabel)
  }
```

**From View Perspective**

```
//create object via Interface with connection to current view
PresenterInterface interface = new Presenter(this);
//call subscriber method from Presenter interface
presenterInterface.getLanguage(id);
```